# Why can't I access a private static method in one half of a partial class from the other half?

Tags: c#, partial-classes

There must be something simple that I'm missing. I have two partial classes, in two different assemblies, and I'm not able to reference a private static method in one partial class from the other partial class.

For example, in the **FirstHalf** assembly, I have the following class:

```
namespace FirstHalf 
{
    public partial class TestPartialClass
    {
        private static void PrintFoo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Foo");
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in the **SecondHalf** assembly, I have the following class:

```
namespace FirstHalf 
{
    public partial class TestPartialClass 
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(PrintFoo());
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I try to invoke `PrintFoo()` from the SecondHalf assembly, I get the following error:

`CS0103: The name 'PrintFoo' does not exist in the current context.`

What's going on, here? I have a reference from SecondHalf to FirstHalf, so Visual Studio does know that there is a dependency between the two.

Comment: You can't split a partial class between two assemblies; they are actually being compiled as two different classes.

Comment: @DanBryant Oh, okay. You should make that an answer, so that I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Not related to what you ask, but you can't pass an expression of type `void` as an argument to `WriteLine`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't split a partial class between two assemblies; they are actually being compiled as two different classes.

If you really want to accomplish something like this across assemblies, with sharing of 'private' members, you can get something similar by creating a base class and inheriting it:

```
namespace FirstHalf
{
    public class Base
    {
        protected static void PrintFoo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Foo");
        }
    }
}

namespace SecondHalf
{
    public class Derived : FirstHalf.Base
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PrintFoo();
        }
    }
}
```

That said, there is probably a cleaner way to accomplish what you're trying to do using some form of composition; the details depend on your particular application.

Comment: Unfortunately, the actual use case for me is an attempt to work around some library limitations. I'll have figure out another way to do what I'm trying to do.

Comment: reflection can be used to hack through 'private' walls

Comment: @quanticle Sounds like this question was a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), you should ask a question explaining what library you are using and what limitation you are running in to and ask about ***that problem*** instead of asking about ***your solution to that problem*** like you did here.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I agree, but unfortunately I'm not sure how much more I can share about what I'm trying to do without submitting proprietary code. In any case, I was able to refactor the code so that I could get everything into a single assembly.